How to Use Appium and Playwright to do UI Tests for .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid Apps
I am trying to do UI Automation for .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid apps. For simplicity I am starting with just doing the automation on the Windows-version of my MauiBlazor app. I have found that (after google searching) for Maui Blazor apps I need to use a combination of an app-based automation tool plus a webdriver based automation tool. I am using Appium and Playwright in a .NET Test project. When the test runs, as a sanity check, I am trying to print out the text of the home page/home screen to the console but I am not finding it.
I am using this sample Maui Blazor app from Microsoft: https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples/tree/main/8.0/MauiBlazorWeb
I created a new test project with Appium and Playwright. I based the design of this test project from this example project on Microsoft's Learn site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/maui-samples/uitest-appium-nunit/
That project alone would work if my app was entirely Maui. But since I have a hybrid app I was only able to launch the app. I can't actually find elements in the BlazorWebView.
Here is my example test.
namespace MauiBlazorWeb.AppiumPlaywright;
public class SampleTests : BaseTest
{
    [Test]
    public async Task SampleTestToCheckHomePage()
    {
        var browser = await Playwright.Chromium.ConnectOverCDPAsync("http://localhost:9222");
        var context = browser.Contexts[0];
        // For some reason there are three pages
        var page = context.Pages[0];
        var page1 = context.Pages[1];
        var page2 = context.Pages[2];

        var pageText0 = await page.ContentAsync();
        var pageText1 = await page1.ContentAsync();
        var pageText2 = await page2.ContentAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Page0 START");
        Console.WriteLine(pageText0);
        Console.WriteLine("Page1 START");
        Console.WriteLine(pageText1);
        Console.WriteLine("Page2 START");
        Console.WriteLine(pageText2);
        Assert.Multiple(() =>
        {
            Assert.That(pageText0.Contains("Welcome to your new app."));
            Assert.That(pageText1.Contains("Welcome to your new app."));
            Assert.That(pageText2.Contains("Welcome to your new app."));
        });

    }
}

Oddly enough Playwright is finding 3 different pages here. I was expecting just one since it is only one BlazorWebView. All three of the asserts fail because it cannot find the home page text.
Also here's the utility code to start the MauiBlazor app with Appium.
First the AppiumSetup class:
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows;

namespace MauiBlazorWeb.AppiumPlaywright;

[SetUpFixture]
public class AppiumSetup
{
    private static AppiumDriver? driver;

    public static AppiumDriver App => driver ?? throw new NullReferenceException("AppiumDriver is null");

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void RunBeforeAnyTests()
    {
        // If you started an Appium server manually, make sure to comment out the next line
        // This line starts a local Appium server for you as part of the test run
        AppiumServerHelper.StartAppiumLocalServer();

        var windowsOptions = new AppiumOptions
        {
            // Specify windows as the driver, typically don't need to change this
            AutomationName = "windows",
            // Always Windows for Windows
            PlatformName = "Windows",
            // The identifier of the deployed application to test
            App = "com.companyname.mauiblazorweb.maui_9zz4h110yvjzm!App",
        };

        // Note there are many more options that you can use to influence the app under test according to your needs

        driver = new WindowsDriver(windowsOptions);

    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void RunAfterAnyTests()
    {
        driver?.Quit();

        // If an Appium server was started locally above, make sure we clean it up here
        AppiumServerHelper.DisposeAppiumLocalServer();
    }
}

Then the AppiumServerHelper class:
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Service;

namespace MauiBlazorWeb.AppiumPlaywright;

public static class AppiumServerHelper
{
    private static AppiumLocalService? _appiumLocalService;

    public const string DefaultHostAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    public const int DefaultHostPort = 4723;

    public static void StartAppiumLocalServer(string host = DefaultHostAddress,
        int port = DefaultHostPort)
    {
        if (_appiumLocalService is not null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .WithIPAddress(host)
            .UsingPort(port);

        // Start the server with the builder
        _appiumLocalService = builder.Build();
        _appiumLocalService.Start();
    }

    public static void DisposeAppiumLocalServer()
    {
        _appiumLocalService?.Dispose();
    }
}

Majority of the code is basically from the two code bases I already linked. The actual test is the one I created.
Can someone help me on how we can do UI test automation on the .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid apps?
I would attach the test output but it exceeds the character limit for this question. You'll be able to see it if you run my test locally.

Did you have any success getting it to work?
